# How to use a <div> with a chart using innerHTML

Tags: html, charts, innerhtml

I have a code like following:

```
 w1.innerHTML = "<h2>" + name + "</h2><h3>Abc</h3>";
```

It is working fine. I want to pass a div instead of `"<h2>" + name + "</h2><h3>Abc</h3>";` The div will show a chart. The div is as following:

```
 <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

and the div is showing a chart using following code:

```
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '°C'
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
            }]
        });
    });
```

So the output will be a chart instead of showing a text. How can I do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: var w1= document.getElementById("container");

Comment: I don't understand your question then, why not just remove the `w1.innerHTML = "<h2>" + name + "</h2><h3>Abc</h3>";` line and use you highcharts function if you are just wanting to show the highcharts?

Comment: I was trying something like this:
w1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('container').outerHTML;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
$('#container').highcharts({
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '°C'
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
            }]
        });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid black;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Demo 1: http://jsfiddle.net/DQGY8/**

---

**Update:**

I maded other versions of this Fiddle, I hope something can help you

Have a look also here:

**Demo 3: http://jsfiddle.net/DQGY8/3**

Comment: Nope. I want to pass a div id instead of a text so that the innerHTML generates the div with the chart.

Comment: I don't understand what do you want exactly, but I tried to Update my JSFiddle, have a look http://jsfiddle.net/DQGY8/1

Comment: I maded another update, if you want to assign a specific chart to a specific ID: http://jsfiddle.net/DQGY8/2/